# Postgres: optimize performance for URN JOIN matching vs INT

Tags: postgresql, performance, join

In our database we are thinking using URNs everywhere, instead of IDs.

e.g. urn:ny:MyTypeOfObject:123

Testing the performance on

```
CREATE table addresses AS 
SELECT 
i as id_int,
CONCAT('urn:ny:address:', i::text) as id_urn
FROM 
generate_series(1, 100000000) s(i);  -- 100M


CREATE table addresses_attrib AS 
SELECT 
i as id_int,
CONCAT('urn:ny:address:', i::text) as id_urn,
i%79 as random_filter
FROM 
generate_series(1, 10000000) s(i); -- 10M

-- CREATE index both on id_int and id_urn
CREATE index int_a1 on addresses(id_int);
CREATE index int_aa1 on addresses_attrib(id_int);
CREATE index urn_a1 on addresses(id_urn);
CREATE index urn_aa1 on addresses_attrib(id_urn);
```

```
SELECT * FROM addresses_attrib aa
JOIN addresses a on (aa.id_int=a.id_int)
WHERE aa.random_filter=4
LIMIT 100000
```

VS

```
SELECT * FROM addresses_attrib aa
JOIN addresses a on (aa.id_urn=a.id_urn)
WHERE aa.random_filter=4
LIMIT 100000
```

Using pg_bench, the int based one is about twice as fast (0.5 avg the int) compared to the urn one (1.2s average) according to pg_bench.

Is there any way to speed up this kind of joins on URNs?

Comment: Please fix the syntax errors in your code.

Comment: It should be fixed now: https://extendsclass.com/postgresql/57f626c

Comment: Turn track_io_timing on, then use `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` to look at the plans of the two queries, to see why they differ.  That might suggest what you can do about it.

Comment: I get a vastly larger difference than 2 fold, but that seems to come own to the different ordering of the data, not the different types.  The way you generate the data there is a perfect correlation between the number values and the row order, but an imperfect correlation between the number-cast-to string values and the row order.

Comment: This seems like a very implausible test case.  It would be quite odd for the attribute table to have 10 fold fewer rows than the parent table.  And even odder for all those ones that do match to be all at one end of the key space.  And what is the point of the query in the first place?  Why do you care what an *arbitrarily chosen* 4 or 100,000 joined rows (out of 10,000,000 total) would be?  Should there be an ORDER BY in there?

Comment: 1) it seems a pure "more cpu time" consumption 2) Does ordering really matter with a hash join? I'll try to come up with a more sparse ordering 3) the table schema is just for the sake of the example, addresses_attrib could be addresses_with_insurance, not everything has an insurance owner, my real case is comparable. I wouldn't focus too much on the schema or the query per se. The point of the question is about finding an indexing solution that would allow URN and INT join performance being comparable.

Comment: I don't know if/that it *is* using a hash join.  I rather suspect it is not, as you aren't going to hash 100M rows in 1.2 second.

Comment: those are actual performance numbers, with powerful machines I'm experimenting with (1TB ram, top tier CPUs for 2022)